# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

My Flutter app was updated to the latest version of Flutter and I added firebase_messaging to my app. After this was done, this application works fine on an emulator but crashes when I try to run it on an actual iOS device, with this error:

```
  -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddcb9ee0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddcb9ee0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18c8959d8 0x1a0bfeb54 0x18c7a5bbc 0x18c89801c 0x18c899f8c 0x102deadcc 0x102dec698 0x102deb1a8 0x102dea8bc 0x18c4cd298 0x18c4ce280 0x18c4aa4f0 0x18c4aafdc 0x18c4b4800 0x1d4f3b5a4 0x1d4f3e874)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
* thread #5, queue = 'com.google.firebase.auth.globalWorkQueue', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001b86f484c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x1b86f484c <+8>:  b.lo   0x1b86f4868               ; <+36>
    0x1b86f4850 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1b86f4854 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1b86f4858 <+20>: bl     0x1b86d1f5c               ; cerror_nocancel
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
```

I have tried everything, ranging from removing messaging from the app to checking to see that "Push Notifications" and "Background Fetch" has been enabled in Xcode, but the app still keeps crashing. The error logs show that the crash is from `firebase.auth.globalWorkQueue` and the app launches just fine on an emulator. I removed firebase_messaging and the app still crashes when run on an emulator. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: At this point I have tried everything. From running “flutter pub cache repair” to even even entirely deleting the iOS folder. When I downgrade my packages sometimes the app runs on debug mode but when I run “flutter run —release” the app still crashes on startup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after about a week of sleepless nights, shuffling dependencies, downgrading, upgrading packages and versions turns out the problem was from my flutter code. With the null safety changes. Pushing a null value to the native Firebase SDK causes a crash rather than an error and I was getting unchecked null values from my shared preferences. I expected an error in my code but a crash came so it kept breaking. If you see the error above in your code you’re probably pushing a null value into a sign in function. Check that

Comment: By this do you mean the firebase auth login function?

Comment: See also https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/6900

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error stemmed from Location permission. When building and running the app with Xcode I chose Always allow permission. Then all other builds resulted with NSInvalidArgumentException'.

Flutter clean, Xcode clean build folder, nothing helped. Only solution was to remove the app from iPhone manually then build it again. Seems like when building and running the app with Xcode Allow When Using permission is the way to go. As the app only works when the phone is connected to Xcode at this stage. Selecting Always Allow causes this error for all next builds.